# Compile with API 21 [Android L]

Tags: android, sdk

When I try to create a Android Project with **Android L** , m targeting min and target sdk as **API 21** [Android L] , but compile with option doent hv API 21 and hence i m not able to generate R since it take Android Api 20 for Compilation .

[image]

In Above ScreenShot : compile with option doesnt show API 21.

Comment: Do you have the relevant packages downloaded from Android SDK manager?

Comment: yeah i have all android L packages

Comment: For me, I am using Android Studio and I can choose android-L in my Compile SDK version. However, for Build Tool version, I only have 20.0.0

Comment: i m willing  to creata project in eclipse only

Comment: Create project as you are doing. After that set build target to L from properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Android L need java 7  hence i checked java in ubuntu **javac -version**  but since my java version on ubuntu was 6 it didnt worked :(

Other reasons Android L may not work :

1. Ensure u have java 7
2. Update latest ADT
3. Layout[DesignView] contains API 20 as below :
   [image]

Below was the error i was getting in eclipse :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Android L is still in Preview / Beta mode, so you can't do anything with it yet. If you're planning to develop on Android 5.0 (Android L or Android API 21), then wait a little while till Google had brushed up all the kinks for this release.

Also AFAIK, there's no mobile devices out there that run Android 5.0.

Comment: nope my functionality works in another system , i m just trying to find whats wrong on ubuntu

Comment: Well then in that case, I guess you'll need to inform Google that they need to drop the "Preview" note with Android L in their Android SDK Manager distributions for Linux, Mac and Windows. ;)

Comment: thats alreay available thx for info ..provide valid comments plz

Comment: What a funny solution!! Preview has been given to test, right?

Comment: @PankajKumar: I guess you don't know what "Preview" mean then. Have you read the Android L documentation back to front, especially the part where it says that Android L is **only** a "temporary" release. "Temporary" does not mean official in Google or anyone else's term, AFAIK.

Comment: @ChuongPham :D :D really? No I did not read because I do not know English :D :D. For your kind information, I have developed and tested all new features of Lollipop using L preview.

Comment: @PankajKumar: Then read the spec first in the future before you comment. Thanks.

Comment: @ChuongPham `AFAIK, Android L is still in Preview / Beta mode, so you can't do anything with it yet` what does it mean? What I can not do with it? They provided preview, just for joking? By the way I do not want to continue this senseless conversation.